# WinJS.Binding.List.createFiltered: async call in predicate

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

The predicate in the code below will always return false.
My question is how can I 'wait' for the async operation and use that result as the predicate result?

```
return someList.createFiltered(function(item) {                        
         var filter = false;
         var promise = someOperationAsync();

         promise.done(function(b) {
              filter = b;
         });

         return filter;
});
```

Comment: Hm, wouldn't it be better to return the promise and wait for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async predicates aren't supported in the WinJS.Binding.List, unfortunately. The only way I can think to do this--i.e. block the UI thread synchronously--is to sit in a loop at the end, watching a Boolean flag that's set in the completed handler and the error handler (and you'd have to use an error handler on the promise in this case to change that flag).

What are you trying to accomplish with the async call? Would it be possible to cache those results when the app starts such that you can do a synchronous lookup against that cached data?

Comment: This piece of code is just simplifying my problem :) I am trying to update the item with a translation of some text, to get the translation I am using a webservice call which is async. I tried it with a converter but returning a promise from it is not supported. After that I tried to use this (hacky) method. Both have the same problem, 'waiting for a promise'.

Comment: Why are you using a filter though for that? Why not just update the underlying data?

Comment: You ask a good question--the purpose of a filter is to narrow down the items available in the filtered projection, and its return value is a Boolean (true to include the item in the projection, false to exclude). So it's not meant to modify values in the list at all--that should be done directly in the data source, and because of data binding it will update the ListView as well as any other projections (including filtered ones). Your code to perform those translations can happen elsewhere and involve async calls.

Answer (score -1):

You need to return the promise and then call 'then' or 'done' from the calling function.

Alternatively you could put `return filter;` inside the promise.done section, but then effectively it'd be running syncronously as you'd be waiting for the result of the promise before returning.

Comment: That won't work in this case, as the methods in the projection class (FilteredListProjection, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh920299.aspx) assumes it can call the predicate synchronously, and that the predicate returns the expected result, rather than a promise. Putting a return statement inside promise.done won't do anyting, as that return value goes into the WinJS.Promise implementation and not to the outside caller.

Comment: Ah ok, I wasn't aware the promise couldn't be returned from the predicate.
Wouldn't putting return in the promise.done wait for the done method of the promise before returning the result to the createFiltered function?

Comment: The predicate returns true or false to indicate whether the item is included in the filtered projection. The completed handler given to a promise does not return that value from promise.done or promise.then. With promise.then, the return value from the completed handler will be the value delivered by the *different* promise returned from promise.then, but that's for chaining promises and not returning values as being attempted here.